# UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE after `apt install npm`

Tags: apt, 20.04, ssl, npm

I'm actually attempting to install gTile, which requires Bazelisk.

On a relatively clean system:

```
$ sudo apt install npm
# takes almost 5 minutes, then:
$ npm install -g @bazel/bazelisk
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@bazel%2fbazelisk failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/celiyah/.npm/_logs/2021-05-17T16_21_40_542Z-debug.log
```

Based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22263280/2496266) I also tried:

```
$ npm install ssl-root-cas
npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! errno UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/ssl-root-cas failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/celiyah/.npm/_logs/2021-05-17T16_23_34_826Z-debug.log
```

It would appear the `npm` install on Ubuntu is broken?

```
$ npm --version
6.14.8
```

Has anyone run into this error, and how does one fix it (without disabling security)?

On that note please don't mention turning SSL off. This is a secure machine and I'd like to keep it that way. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error disappears after reboot; after you `sudo apt install npm`, reboot the computer.